# Find invoices equal zero without discount Pandas Dataframe

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, having

In Pandas, I have a dataframe like this:

```
| Division |  Invoice |   Transactions | Amount |
|----------|----------|----------------|--------|
|   Europe | 10000000 | Product Charge |   1000 |
|   Europe | 10001000 | Product Charge |   1000 |
|   Europe | 10001000 |       Discount |   -500 |
|    Latam | 10002000 | Product Charge |      0 |
|    Latam | 10003000 | Product Charge |   1000 |
|    Latam | 10003000 |       Discount |  -1000 |
|   Europe | 10004000 | Product Charge |    500 |
|   Europe | 10004000 |       Discount |   -500 |
|   Europe | 10005000 | Product Charge |    500 |
|   Europe | 10005000 |       Discount |    495 |
|    Latam | 10006000 | Product Charge |      0 |
|    Latam | 10007000 | Product Charge |      0 |
|    Latam | 10007000 |  Loyalty bonus |    200 |
```

I need to build a new DF that sum and count for each `division`, when invoice amount = 0 and Discount = 0 , something like this:

| Division | Invoice | Total | Q_Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Latam | 10002000 | 0 | 1 |
| Latam | 10006000 | 0 | 1 |

In SQL I can calculate it as follows, but in Pandas DF i can't replicate it:

```
SELECT Division, Invoice, SUM (Amount) Total, COUNT (DISTINCT Invoice) Q_Invoice
FROM df
GROUP BY Division,  Invoice
HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN Transactions =  'Discount' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = '0'
       AND SUM (CASE WHEN Transactions = 'Product Charge' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= '1'
       AND SUM(Amount) = 0
```

I tried to replicate the above result in a jupyter notebook using pandassql but it is not working, use the following calculation:

```
import pandasql as ps
import pandas as pd

 df2 = ps.sqldf ("""SELECT Division, Invoice, SUM (Amount) Total,COUNT (DISTINCT Invoice) Q_Invoice 
                   FROM df
                   GROUP BY Division,  Invoice
                   HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN Transactions =  'Discount' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = '0'
                   AND SUM (CASE WHEN Transactions = 'Product Charge' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= '1'
                   AND SUM(Amount) = 0 """)
```

I don't know how to proceed, I'm new to pandas

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can `.pivot_table` the datafame and then filter by sum of Product Charge:

```py
x = df.pivot_table(
    index=["Division", "Invoice"],
    columns="Transactions",
    values="Amount",
    aggfunc=["sum", "count"],
    fill_value=0,
)
x = x[x[("sum", "Product Charge")].eq(0)].reset_index()
x.columns = x.columns.map("_".join)
x = x.rename(
    columns={
        "Division_": "Division",
        "Invoice_": "Invoice",
        "sum_Product Charge": "Total",
        "count_Product Charge": "Q_Invoice",
    }
)[["Division", "Invoice", "Total", "Q_Invoice"]]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  Division   Invoice  Total  Q_Invoice
0    Latam  10002000      0          1
1    Latam  10006000      0          1
```

Comment: Almost, How to solve when an invoice has another charge with a value> 0, for example "Loyalty Bonus" = 200 but Product Charge = 0. The above causes that the invoice is not equal to zero and it would not work in your solution
I have added the case in the example df